# What is this pan made of?

Tags: seasoning-pans

Thinking this was carbon steel, I tried to strip it using the canned tomatoes technique, and a lot of elbow grease.

The sides are still black and very hard to clean, but the bottom of the pan reached the metallic color I was expecting.
What I didn’t expect though was to discover what looks like a film, either translucent or of a different metallic color, which is starting to strip down although it doesn’t come off easily.

Hopefully the pictures I attached will be good enough.

The main question is "what is this pan made of?", and the bonus question is "can I still restore it to a useable state, or should I just get a new one?"

[image: The whole pan from above. The weird scratches/layers on the bottom are already noticeable at this scale.]
The whole pan from above. The weird scratches/layers on the bottom are already noticeable at this scale.

[image: A close-up of what's looking weird to me: it looks like a layer on top of the metal is peeling off.]
A close-up of what's looking weird to me: it looks like a layer on top of the metal is peeling off.

[image: And for reference, this is what the pan's bottom looks like. I don't know if it is clear but it has a blueish tint.]
And for reference, this is what the pan's bottom looks like. I don't know if it is clear but it has a blueish tint.

Comment: Adding this as it might help identification, but I still need help please.
I looked up a few things, found [an item that looks very similar](https://hands.net/goods/4903449116355/) (I live in Japan), and after translating, it looks like it could be hard nitriding cast iron?

Comment: Do magnets stick to it? If so, do they stick strongly, or poorly?

Comment: The first and last picture look like my wok (without the effects of the second picture). It is of stainless steel. I got it from a vietnamese cooker who said it was the best type to buy (oil it after use for non chinese dishes) about 10 years ago. (magnets stick strongly to the sides)

Comment: was it maybe some kind of nonstick coating (teflon)?

Comment: @Esther that’s one thing I’m pretty sure it’s not!

Comment: That patchy layer looks a lot like seasoning.  It would be interesting to see what soaking in ammonia does to it.